# Can't install Github for Windows

Tags: github-for-windows

Whenever i try to install github (gui) from online installer it stops in between and gives : cannot retrieve application. 
Is there any other way or Solution to this?

Comment: You should probably contact Github's support directly.

Comment: I did, no reply so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was exactly 'tamper protection' of my AV.
Turned AV off for time. Worked.